# Is it possible to add Xamarin.forms code to an existing Native Android Studio Application as a library?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xamarin.forms, android-library

I have an existing Native Android Application - written in Java on Android Studio.

A client wanted to add some new features that were being developed by another team and a different company that they wanted to include in this Android App as well. The other team is completing the work as a Xamarin.Forms format as they are more comfortable writing in C#.

I have seen sources online for including native iOS and Android code in a Xamarin project. But haven't found any examples of integrating a Xamarin.Form into an existing Android application.

Was it possible to integrate Xamarin.forms into an Android Studio application? (Possibly as a library?)
Were there any good resources about the different options doing this?

Comment: Maybe this could help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/dotnet-embedding/index .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no supported mechanism to create a library in C# using Xamarin.droid that can be called from java.